# Read Key Value(s) Pair(Json Format) from a file in C++ in a MAP

Tags: c++, json, boost

Hi I am new to programming world of C++ (Beginner).
My query is I have a JSON File (Key, Value(s) format), which need to accessed by C++ and store in Map(Key, Value(s)).

JSON File:

```
{
    "1": [
        4
    ],
    "2": [
        3
    ],
    "3": [
        1
    ],
    "4": [
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6
    ],
    "5": [
        5
    ],
    "6": [
        3
    ]
    "7": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10
    ]
}
```

Comment: You're going to want to find a JSON library to handle this for you.

Comment: A well known JSON library for C++ is https://github.com/nlohmann/json. With this, after reading your JSON data into a C++ JSON object this may be queried (accessed) like a map, so that there is no need to store in another Map data structure.

Comment: thanks StefanQ and Stephen Newell for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

1) Get the json library(https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoncpp/)
2) Extract it.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "json_cpp-master/json/json.h"
#include "json_cpp-master/json/reader.h"
#include "json_cpp-master/json/value.h"
using namespace std;
int main(){
    Json::Value root;
    Json::CharReaderBuilder reader;

    ifstream file("file.json");
    file >> root;

    cout << root[2][1];
    cout << root;
    return 0;
}
```

3)Then Do the following:-
sudo apt-get install libjsoncpp-dev 
and
sudo ln -s /usr/include/jsoncpp/json/ /usr/include/json

4)Run the program :- g++ program.cpp -ljsoncpp -o program

Comment: thanks a lot for this. I did as the instructions says and it perfectly worked. Loved it.